# Does Selenium Webdriver 2.53 supports Firefox 46.0?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using `webdriver` 2.46 with `firefox` 41.0.1 is fine. Now I upgraded `webdriver` and `firefox` to 2.53 and 46.0. Lots of test scripts failed with updated one but those run successfully with old versions.

Anybody faces this issue? any idea?

Comment: I used to work with that combination and it worked, Did you manage to find the line/s in your code where it happens? Are you sure it's not timing issues (46.0 loads data or renders slower etc..)? Can you paste some selenium and HTML code that used to work?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. (selenium 2.53 and Firefox 46.0) It appears that with version 2.52 and 2.51, selenium corrects an overlapping(see below).But without that update, Firefox had more flexibility. It became more fragile with latest updates.

**As you can see here:**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG

> 2.52 : 
>   Updated Firefox driver to include ability to disable overlapping
>   element    check. This includes a new constant for the name of the
>   capability.
>
> 2.51 : Updated Firefox driver which includes fixes for the clicking in
>   overlapped    elements. In keeping with project support policy for
>   Firefox, This driver    has been tested with Firefox 44 (current
>   release), 43 (immediately prior    release), 38 (current ESR release),
>   and 31 (immediately prior ESR release).

They update the Firefox driver and makes him more fragile and make the user experience as realistic as possible(because the user can't click on something he didn't see ,of course).

I had version 2.47 and firefox 40 before, and like you, lot of test failed with new version.

**The solution:**

Make sure to scroll into the page to see the elements you want to click on or validate.If the element is at the bottom of the page and your element is under an other, try to hide the object over.

Use the **JavascriptExecutor**  included in selenium package
to  do your manipulations as shown here : 
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/scrolling-web-page-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Hope it helps